# USB installation error with UEFI

Tags: usb-installation

I am using a bootable drive to install Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) but its shows two errors:

> 1- 'casper/vmlinuz' not found. 
> 2- you need to load kernel first.

Comment: (1) Make sure the ISO you're burning isn't corrupt. (2) Use a different tool to burn the ISO.

Comment: How did you create the USB device?

Comment: Did the media verification complete?  and did you perform the ISO validation before writing to your media.  The most likely explanation for your error was failing one of those checks, ie. invalid/corrupt ISO & far more likely in my experience poor/invalid write to your installation media.